# Creating unique and merging existing row in database with JPA

Tags: java, jpa, orm, persistence

I have 2 tables: `User` and `Loan`.
`User` have 3 fields: `id` (PK), `first_name` and `last_name`. `Loan` table have field `user_id` that is foreign key to `User` table:
[image]

By persisting a new `Loan` I need to create new `User` if his `first_name` and `last_name` are unique, otherwise put his `id` in `uder_id`.

The source code of my Loan class:

```
 public class Loan {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private Long sum;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

... methods ...
```

I'm using this method to persist new `User`:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em; 

public void save(User user) {
    if (user.getId() == null) {
         em.persist(user);
    } else {
         em.merge(user);
    }
}
```

And when I try to save a new `Loan` it always persists a new `User` with the same `first_name` and `last_name` but different `id`.

```
 loan.setSum(sum);
 loan.setUser(new User(firstName, lastName));
 loanService.save(loan);
```

To use user's `first_name` and `last_name` as a PK is not a solution, I need an `id`.

**UPDATE_1**

I tried to find `User` by his name:

```
public User findByName(String firstName, String lastName) {
        TypedQuery<User> query = em.createQuery(
                "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.firstName = :firstName " +
                        "AND u.lastName = :lastName", User.class)
                .setParameter("firstName", firstName).setParameter("lastName", lastName);
        return query.getSingleResult();
    }
```

But when I enter new user I got an exception:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: #{loanBean.requestLoan()}: javax.persistence.NoResultException: getSingleResult() did not retrieve any entities.
```

And when I enter existing user, it adds a new one with the same `firstName` and `lastName` but new `id`.
When I repeat this operation I got another exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: More than one result was returned from Query.getSingleResult()
```

**UPDATE_2**
Thanks a lot Pietro Boido for your really helpful suggestions.I created unique index on `first_name` and `last_name` fields in DB and refactor the `save()` method. But now when I enter existing user's data I got new exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'FIRST_LAST_NAME' defined on 'USER'.
Error Code: 20000
```

Comment: I am not going to answer directly to your question, but i think this logic is completely related to your Business layer, and must be put out of Data Access Logic.

Comment: you are right, I updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first execute a query to find the user by name and create a new one only if it was not found:

```
User user = userService.find(firstName, lastName);
if (user == null) {
    user = loanService.createUser(new User(firstName, lastName));
}
loan.setSum(sum);
loan.setUser(user);
loanService.save(loan);
```

Since there might be no user with the given name, use getResultList when you query for the user, because getSingleResult expects to always find a result.

```
List<User> users = query.getResultList();
if (!users.isEmpty()) {
    return users.iterator().next();
} else {
    return null;
}
```

The code assumes that the database has a unique index on first_name, last_name.

You should not cascade operations on the ManyToOne relationship. Think about this: if you delete a loan, should the user be deleted too?

Cascading operations should be used when the related entity is part of the relating entity and their life cycles are managed together.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="loans")
public class Loan implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "total")
    private Long sum;
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    //...
}
```

Here is a possible working example:

```
@Stateless
public class LoanService implements LoanServiceRemote {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public User createUser(User user) {
        em.persist(user);
        return user;
    }

    @Override
    public Loan createLoan(Loan loan) {
        em.persist(loan);
        System.out.println("loan persisted: id=" + loan.getId());
        return loan;
    }

    @Override
    public Loan saveLoan(Loan loan) {
        em.merge(loan);
        return loan;
    }

    @Override
    public Long incrementLoan(Integer loanId, long amount) {
        Loan loan = em.find(Loan.class, loanId);
        if (loan != null) {
            long sum = loan.getSum() + amount;
            /*
             * The entity is bound to the entity manager,
             * because it was returned by the find method.
             * We can simply set its properties and
             * the entity manager will update the datasource
             * after the method returns and the transaction commits. 
             * No need to call persist or merge.
             */
            loan.setSum(sum);
            return sum;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deleteLoan(Integer loanId) {
        Loan loan = em.find(Loan.class, loanId);
        if (loan != null) {
            em.remove(loan);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Loan findLoan(Integer loanId) {
        return em.find(Loan.class, loanId);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Loan> requestLoans(LoanRequest loanRequest) {
        User user;
        TypedQuery<User> query = em.createQuery("select user from User user where user.firstName = :firstName and user.lastName = :lastName", User.class);
        query.setParameter("firstName", loanRequest.getFirstName());
        query.setParameter("lastName", loanRequest.getLastName());
        List<User> users = query.getResultList();
        if (users.isEmpty()) {
            user = new User();
            user.setFirstName(loanRequest.getFirstName());
            user.setLastName(loanRequest.getLastName());
            //new entities must be persisted
            em.persist(user);
        } else {
            user = users.get(0);
        }

        List<Loan> loans = new ArrayList<>();
        Long[] totals = loanRequest.getTotals();
        for (int i = 0; i < totals.length; i++) {
            Loan loan = new Loan();
            loan.setSum(totals[i]);
            loan.setUser(user);
            em.persist(loan);
            loans.add(loan);
        }

        return loans;
    }
}
```

A unit test:

```
@Test
public void testLoan() {
    User user = loanService.createUser(newUser());

    Loan loan1 = new Loan();
    loan1.setSum(10L);
    loan1.setUser(user);

    Loan loan2 = loanService.createLoan(loan1);
    assertNotNull(loan2);

    Integer loanId = loan2.getId();

    assertNotNull(loanId);
    assertEquals(loan1.getSum(), loan2.getSum());
    assertEquals(loan1.getUser(), user);

    User user2 = loanService.createUser(newUser());
    loan2.setUser(user2);
    loan2.setSum(20L);
    Loan loan3 = loanService.saveLoan(loan2);
    assertLoanEquals(loan2, loan3);

    Long total = loanService.incrementLoan(loanId, 10L);
    assertNotNull(total);
    assertEquals((Long)(loan3.getSum() + 10L), total);

    loan3.setSum(total);

    Loan loan4 = loanService.findLoan(loanId);
    assertLoanEquals(loan3, loan4);

    boolean result = loanService.deleteLoan(loanId);
    assertTrue(result);

    Loan loan5 = loanService.findLoan(loanId);
    assertNull(loan5);

    Long[] totals = new Long[]{1L,2L,3L};
    LoanRequest loanRequest = new LoanRequest();
    loanRequest.setFirstName("Amerigo");
    loanRequest.setLastName("Vespucci");
    loanRequest.setTotals(totals);

    List<Loan> loans = loanService.requestLoans(loanRequest);
    assertNotNull(loans);
    assertEquals(3, loans.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        assertEquals(totals[i], loans.get(i).getSum());
        loanService.deleteLoan(loans.get(i).getId());
    }


}

void assertLoanEquals(Loan loan1, Loan loan2) {
    assertNotNull(loan1);
    assertNotNull(loan2);
    assertEquals(loan1.getSum(), loan2.getSum());
    assertUserEquals(loan1.getUser(), loan2.getUser());
    assertEquals(loan1.getId(), loan2.getId());
}
void assertUserEquals(User user, User user2) {
    assertNotNull(user);
    assertNotNull(user2);
    assertEquals(user.getId(), user2.getId());
    assertEquals(user.getFirstName(), user2.getFirstName());
    assertEquals(user.getLastName(), user2.getLastName());
}
```

Comment: thank you for suggestion, I tried this and update my question.

Comment: I think the problem is somewhere here: `@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` because when I changed `CascadeType` to `MERGE` it was working as I need until I add a new `User`

Comment: As I put `@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})` I'm able only to create new users. When I try to enter existing one I got: 'SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'FIRST_LAST_NAME' defined on 'CLIENT'. Error Code: 20000'

Comment: @DimaSan I Suggest removing cascade operations from the ManyToOne annotation. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Pietro!